# Word Roulette / Bingo draw animation on my “.output” section

Tags: javascript, animation

so basically I’m quite new to coding and I’m working on this project where just like bingo I want to draw a random number from  from my array as the final draw. No problems with this I’ve already figured this out. However I still want to create an animation where my output box displays some of the other numbers in the array before landing on the final draw. The animation doesn’t necessarily need to be from the array itself but just a little load screen before presenting the final product. Any help?

So far I haven’t found any way to make this happen except by using the .then() method but it’s still not quite what I imagined in my mind any help would be awesome

Comment: `not quite what I imagined` we can't know what you imagined, nor can we see the code you currently have

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.